How to retry a rpc subscription using web3.js 2.0?
I'm trying to create a long-lived websocket connection with web3.js 2.0 but I'm not sure how to reconnect after a disconnection.
This creates the subscription:
const wsSubscription = createSolanaRpcSubscriptions(url)

let abortController = new AbortController();
let logsNotifications = await wsSubscription
    .logsNotifications({mentions: [wallet.address]}, { commitment: "confirmed"})
    .subscribe({ abortSignal: abortController.signal })


async function logsSub() {
    try {
        for await (let notification of logsNotifications) {
            // do stuff
        }
    } catch (e) {
       // reconnect
    }
}

logsSub()

After a disconnection, the catch block is run. What should be done to reconnect?

Maybe this is a silly question, but can you just do the same thing you did earlier, ie. wsSubscription.logsNotifications(...).subscribe(...)?
